# getattribute and tag value using dom

Tags: php, dom

There are similar threads available. I look on them and tried to get. Here i can get the address value but `phone` number and `image url` is not comming.

Where I make mistake here?

```
function getData($url){
        $containers1 = $html->find('div.mapbox div.mapbox-text strong.street-address address');   
    foreach($containers1 as $container)
    {
        $comments = $container->find('span');
        $item = new stdClass();
        foreach($comments as $comment)
        {
            $address.= $comment->plaintext; //append the content of each span
        }
        echo $address; // this gives correct result
    }
    $containers2 = $html->find('div.mapbox div.mapbox-text span.biz-phone');
    $phone = $containers2->innertext;
        echo "<br/>".$phone."<br/>"; // no result
    $Imgcontainers = $html->find('div.js-photo photo photo-1 div.showcase-photo-box img');
        echo $Imgcontainers->getAttribute('src'); // Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
}   
    }
    $url = 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/locanda-san-francisco?start=40';
    $root = getData($url);
```

**UPDATE**

I added this:

```
    $Imgcontainers = $html->find('div.photo-1 img');
    foreach($Imgcontainers as $cont){               
        $img[] = $cont->getAttribute('src');            
    }
    echo $img[0];
```

http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Pf2RTD8pNdy-oUnp-57m4Q/ls.jpghttp://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Pf2RTD8pNdy-oUnp-57m4Q/ls.jpg

Same url twice? why twice though we echo only 0th array value?

Comment: Are you using Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Comment: Simply use one unique class for read image tag $Imgcontainers = $html->find('div.photo-1 img');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
foreach($containers1 as $container)
{
  $comments = $container->find('span');
  $item = new stdClass();
  foreach($comments as $comment)
  {
        $address.= $comment->plaintext; //append the content of each span
  }
  echo $address; // this gives correct result
}
$containers2 = $html->find('div.mapbox div.mapbox-text span.biz-phone');
foreach($containers2 as $contact){
    $phone = $contact->plaintext;
}   
echo "<br/>".$phone."<br/>"; // no result
$Imgcontainers = $html->find('div.photo-1 img');
foreach($Imgcontainers as $cont){
    echo $cont->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but it gives - `http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Pf2RTD8pNdy-oUnp-57m4Q/ls.jpg//s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/photo/qifZoydAoHDzenurxpsM0Q/30s.jpg ` I changed it to `find('div.showcase-photo-box img'); ` which gives 'http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Pf2RTD8pNdy-oUnp-57m4Q/ls.jpghttp://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/WWcu9lz65KLtOTsFZnIHPw/ls.jpghttp://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/NWYEgpRzMiAFrGvs_6aQAQ/ls.jpghttp://s3-media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/hQKPu2XQ8YUUBvkZgfvXcA/180s.jpghttp://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Njz41l4ku_uQLuwqiuLIu...'

Comment: Use some array variables like `$img[] = $cont->getAttribute('src');` then we can get all the images in array.